# is it ok for Composer autoloader to have classes that from require-dev that don't exist?

Tags: composer-php

I am using Composer autoloader in my project for my own classes.

I am also using PHPUnit, and so my composer.json has this:

`"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": ">=3.5"
  },`

This means that my composer autoloader files has support for the PHPUnit classes. This is great for me when I want to run tests.

I have so far avoided from committing the version of the autoloader files that has mentions of all the PHPUnit files. However, this is proving rather a pain in developing, as I keep having to switch between two versions of the autoloader files.

Is it ok to just commit them?

Answer (score 0):

> I have so far avoided from committing the version of the autoloader
>   files that has mentions of all the PHPUnit files. However, this is
>   proving rather a pain in developing, as I keep having to switch
>   between two versions of the autoloader files.
>
> Is it ok to just commit them?

If i understand this correctly, then you want to commit parts (`vendor/composer`) or the full vendor folder to your repository, right?

This would make it complicated for everyone in your development team, because 
of overwrites in the vendor folder, when they run dependency updates using Composer (including autoload re-generation) and also because of possible merge conflicts, when pulling.

**My suggestion is: don't do this! Keep your repository without a vendor folder!**

**Commit `composer.lock` and use `composer install`**

When a developer fetches your repository, it ships without the vendor folder
and the first thing he would do, is to fetch the dependencies by running `composer install`.

Now, to make sure that every developer of your team fetches dependencies with exactly the same versions, you can/should commit the `composer.lock` file.
Composer will also run a bit faster, because it can skip dependency resolution and version lookups, because the information is already in the lock file.

---

**Update**

While i was focues on `require` and `require-dev` to address your question, i forgot to mention that there are also two sections for autoloading `autoload` has an `autoload-dev`.

```
"autoload" : {
    "psr-4": {
        "Application\\": "src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Application\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
```

Referencing: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload-dev

Comment: I want to commit the autoloader because I want my project to be usable in contexts without Composer. The only dependency is PHPUnit, which is in require-dev.

Comment: Well, you could tag a new release, fetch the production dependencies using `composer install --no-dev`, then package it (including vendor dependencies), release it and then deploy it to "your context". | The short answer to your question "Is it ok to just commit them?" is: It will make development complicated, but will work.

Comment: Well the reason I want to commit them is actually to make development simpler, for me at least! At the moment, I keep having to switch between a git branch with the production autoloader and a branch with the development autoloader.

Comment: I've updated my answer and added a note about the `autoload-dev` section, which might also be useful to address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Running `composer install --no-dev` will omit any `require-dev` packages when you are in the process of deploying to production. So the PHPUnit code will not be there.

Comment: Indeed. But my point is that there are two possible version of the autoload files: with PHPUnit and without. My question was: is it safe to commit the autoload files that contain references to PHPUnit files which aren't there?

Comment: Why would you commit the files that will be created anyway? That would only make sense if you also propose to commit all the code in the packages you have. That might make sense for certain deployment scenarios, but it isn't the usual case because of the redundancy that gets version controlled.